# Windows Phone 7 - missing overload for NavigationService.Navigate(object)

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigationservice

I would like to use the NavigationService to create a nice navigation stack in a Windows Phone 7 app.  It seems I can accomplish the objective in SilverLight by using the NavigationService.Navigate(object) method and passing an object similar to the PhoneApplicationPage.

Based on the searching I've done, Windows Phone 7 only allows use of the NavigationService when the  desired output is provided in XAML.  I would like to pass the NavigationService an object I created using C# syntax and not XAML.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

When developing for Windows Phone, there is only one signature for `NavigationService.Navigate` and that is [NavigationService.Navigate(Uri)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591053%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). You're probably reading the documentation for `WPF`.

Comment: Correct, Windows Phone 7 API clearly defines that API as taking a URI only.  Presumably the URI is for a XAML UI layout.  I would like to build my UI using C#, not XAML.  Is that possible?  What if my UI is dynamic?  Do I then need to create XAML for all possible UI variation for each screen... that doesn't seem possible for my particular problem.

Comment: XAML is a markup language and pretty much anything you can do in XAML, you can do in the code-behind. An example of adding controls can be seen here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kirtan007/3110/ . Depending on what you're doing, you can add/remove UI controls from the XAML page using the method in the link. Also, since your UI is in C#, you could take another approach. Have a "host" `XAML` page that contains only a `Border` layout type. Then, depending on the object you want to load, simply set the `Border's` content to be that of your C# UserControl object.